# How can I open 'Add Custom Shortcut' dialog from command line?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, unity, shortcut-keys, customization

> After reading the questions [How to create keyboard shortcuts from terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1092728/how-to-create-keyboard-shortcuts-from-terminal) and [How to set custom keyboard shortcuts from terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597395/how-to-set-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-from-terminal) that explain how we can set a new shortcut from the command line, I have a different doubt:

I would like to know the command I should run to directly open the *Add custom Shortcut* dialog. The same one that I can find going into **Settings > Devices > Keyboard**

[image: Settings > Devices > Keyboard > Add Custom Shortcut]

Comment: I am not sure that exists

Comment: dont want to use the command-line way ?

Comment: I was interested in set a keyboard shortcut to enable quick creation of other hotkeys. At least to learn more about the Ubuntu / Linux / UNIX command line actions. 
Thanks to everybody!